# Автоматизированные системы или автоматические системы

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Автоматизированные системы* или *автоматические системы.*

Встречаются оба варианта. А в чем разница?

Автоматизированные. Кто-то автоматизировал системы, которые раньше не были автоматизированными? Или в таких системах есть элементы автоматики? Автоматизированные частично или полностью.

Автоматические. Их сразу сделали автоматическими? Или в таких системах все элементы связаны с автоматикой?

Comment: Очередной хороший вопрос. Разница относится во-многом к терминологии предметной области и не выводится только лишь из правил русского языка. Хотя определенная языковая логика в самих названиях конечно же есть, но её недостаточно.

Comment: @user190920 Куда вы дели все комментарии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Автоматизированные. Кто-то автоматизировал системы, которые раньше не были автоматизированными?

Да, верно.

А "автоматические" — это не причастие (кто-то что-то сделал), а прилагательное (качество) — они просто работают автоматически (без участия людей). Они могли быть такими изначально, а могли стать позже. Например, система управления могла изначально быть ручной, а потом уже, в результате модернизации, стать автоматической. Тот же AI позволяет этого достичь.

Answer (score 0):

Это разные вещи.

**1. "Автоматизированная система (управления)** представляет собой организационно-техническую систему, обеспечивающую выработку решений на основе автоматизации информационных процессов в различных сферах деятельности (управление, проектирование, производство и тому подобное) или их сочетаниях[1].
В зависимости от области применения даются уточненные формулировки понятия «автоматизированная система». "
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Автоматизированная_система](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Присутствует аспект верховного управления. Более низшие действия автоматизированы и автоматичны.

---

**2. Автоматическая система** - это автомат;
"Автома́т (от др.-греч. automatos — самодействующий)[1]:

Фактически, автоматическими системами могут быть и вовсе не созданные людьми системы, а природные саморегулирующиеся, например :)
И аспект управления, управляющих воздействий тут нигде не обязателен.

*"Или в таких системах все элементы связаны с автоматикой?"* - в общем-то, да;  Может существовать частично автоматическая система, но в полностью автоматической системе - все элементы автоматические, логично.

Comment: *частично автоматическая система* — там речь о автоматизированной.